# How to put these toggles switches side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 toggle switches I'd like to format in two ways. I have fought this and just can't get it. Thank you!

Two formats I'm trying to get are...

Switch1( 0)   Switch2( 0)

and

(This isn't coming accross correctly. Just looking for the switches to be centered below the label.

Switch1  Switch2

( 0)     ( 0)

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fixitrod/v9Lrmkj1/)

HTML:

```
Switch 1
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="centerLockSwitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="centerLockSwitch" value="centerLockSwitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="centerLockSwitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<p>
</p>
Switch 2
<div class="keepScreenOn">
  <input type="checkbox" name="keepScreenOn" class="keepScreenOn-checkbox" id="keepScreenOn" value="keepScreenOn" checked>
  <label class="keepScreenOn-label" for="keepScreenOn">
    <span class="keepScreenOn-inner"></span>
    <span class="keepScreenOn-switch"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 71px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #34A7C1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  margin: 2.5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 43px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}

.keepScreenOn {
  position: relative;
  width: 71px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.keepScreenOn-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.keepScreenOn-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.keepScreenOn-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.keepScreenOn-inner:before,
.keepScreenOn-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.keepScreenOn-inner:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #34A7C1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.keepScreenOn-inner:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.keepScreenOn-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  margin: 2.5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 43px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.keepScreenOn-checkbox:checked + .keepScreenOn-label .keepScreenOn-inner {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.keepScreenOn-checkbox:checked + .keepScreenOn-label .keepScreenOn-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first layout you specified, `display: inline-block` is what you are looking for.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

> `inline-block`:    The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much like a replaced element would)

Let's add some containing divs:

```
<div class="switch-container">
  <div class="title">
    Switch 1
  </div>
  <div class="switch onoffswitch">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="switch-container">
  <div class="title">
    Switch 2
  </div>
  <div class="switch keepScreenOn">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And then apply the `display` value appropriately:

```
.switch-container,
.title,
.switch {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle example for layout #1](https://jsfiddle.net/v9Lrmkj1/1/)

---

For the second layout, a little more tinkering is required:

We can keep the markup the same. However, now, the containers' children elements are block level (they take up the entire width of the container). The containers are not block level because they sit side by side each other horizontally.

As well as adding a fixed width, my approach to fix this would be to apply `inline-flex` rather than `inline-block`, because it makes it easier to horizontally center the items with flexbox's `align-items: center`. Read more about flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

```
.switch-container {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle example for layout #2](https://jsfiddle.net/v9Lrmkj1/10/)

Comment: Thank you! I tried inline-block but didn't have it right. Sure can't wait until I get better at this. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! Please consult my edit for a solution to the second layout.

Comment: Your awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main{
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
}

.wrap1{
width:50%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
}

.wrap2{
width:50%;
height: 100%;
float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="main">
<div class="wrap1"> Put YOUR BUTTON ONE HERE</div>
<div class="wrap2">Put YOUR BUTTON TWO HERE</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Try something like this, put each button in a wrapper and then you can style inside the wrappers.

Comment: I like the wrap idea! I might try it as well. Thank you for the quick response too. You helped me learn something new.